# Como converter um array de bytes de um texto em português sem substituir as letras acentuadas por caracteres especiais em c#?

Tags: c#, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código

`string xmlText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(relFinalProj.XmlAnexo.MidAnexo);`

onde o "relFinalProj.XmlAnexo.MidAnexo" é um array de bytes. Ao realizar o encoding todas as letras acentuadas são substituídas por caracteres especiais como o "?". Como voltar para as letras acentuadas novamente?

Exemplo do texto após o encoding:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você tem que saber qual o Encoding utilizado no texto... então você usa o correto para converter... `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(...)` ou `Encoding.Default.GetString(...)`

Comment: Esse XML é gerado por você? Não seria o caso também de escapar esse conteúdo com o `<![CDATA[]]>`? Assim já se prevenindo em relação à outros caracteres especiais que o texto possa conter e previnir a quebra do xml?